# $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}a_{n}$ converges $\Leftrightarrow $ $\forall k \geqslant 0$, $a_{k}>\sum_{n=k+1}^{+\infty}a_{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Is it true that

$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}a_{n}$ converges $\Leftrightarrow $ $\forall k \geqslant 0$, $a_{k}>\sum_{n=k+1}^{+\infty}a_{n}$

with $a_{n}\geqslant 0$ ?

Comment: It's not true. $\implies$ doesn't hold. For example $a_n = 2^{-n}$

Comment: On the other hand, if $a_k\geq \sum_{n = k+1}^\infty a_n$ (at least for every $k$ large enough) and $a_n\to 0$ then we have convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$. Note that implication from left to right cannot be obtained, even if we want the inequality to hold for large enough $k$, and if we only demand the inequality to be weak, as shows example given by auscrypt.

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not true. Suppose that$$a_n=\begin{cases}1&\text{ if }n=2\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$Then $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ converges, but $0=a_1<\sum_{n=2}^\infty a_n=1$.

Answer (score 2):

No. $a_n = \frac{1}{n^2}$ fails since $a_n < a_{n+1}+a_{n+2}$ for $n \ge 4$.

Answer (score 0):

If
$a_{k}>\sum_{n=k+1}^{+\infty}a_{n}
$
for *any* $k$
then the sum converges
since
$\sum_{n=1}^{k}a_{n}
$
is bounded.